# Why object is not lock while thread is in runnable status?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have class Run. Is simple, just prints , sleeps and then prints;

```
    public class Run implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("START RUN");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(50);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("FINISH RUN");
    }
}
```

Ok now I'm writing test;

```
public static synchronized void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        Run r = new Run();
        Thread t = new Thread(r, "TEST");
        t.start();

        // EXECYTE THE CODE WHULE THREAD "TEST" IS RUNNABLE 
        synchronized (t) {
            System.out.println(t.getState());
            t.wait();
        }
        System.out.println("Y");

        // SLEEP THREAD "TEST" TO BE EXECUTED DURING THE TIME
        Thread.sleep(100);
        synchronized (t) {
            System.out.println(t.getState());
            t.wait();
        }
        System.out.println("Y2");
    }
```

**Question 1:** While thread "TEST" is executing I try to wait(). 
At this moment thread status is "**RUNNABLE**". Because of this status it does **not** wait, I do not understand why? if the status will be "TERMINATED" or "NEW" wait() works; if I remove t.start(), thread status will be "NEW" so wait works too. Could you tell me what happens?

OUTPUT:

```
START RUN
RUNNABLE
FINISH RUN
Y
TERMINATED`
```

Comment: Quick question: what do you think `t.wait()` is doing?

Comment: This only show the state when the thread starts. `Thread.sleep` doesn't lock anything.

Comment: Causes the current thread to wait until another thread invokes notify or notifyAll. when t.wait() is executed, firstly, the thread is sleeping so it does not wait. but after thread will be executed it is hung

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is rather poorly documented. The javadoc of [`Thread#join(long)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join-long-) states

> As a thread terminates the `this.notifyAll` method is invoked. **It is
>   recommended that applications not use `wait`, `notify`, or `notifyAll` on
>   `Thread` instances.**

It's specifically saying don't do what you are currently doing. That is, `synchronized` on a `Thread` object and calling `wait` on that same object.

```
synchronized (t) {
    System.out.println(t.getState());
    t.wait();
}
```

In the current execution of your code. Your main thread reaches the `t.wait()` invocation above while your `TEST` thread is sleeping. `TEST` then wakes up and terminates. As it terminates, it calls `notifyAll` waking up your main thread from the `t.wait()`.

When your main thread then reaches the second `t.wait()`, there's nothing left in your program to wake it up, so your program just hangs.

---

All this to say: **don't use `Thread` object monitors for anything**.

Comment: And just to be clear, by "recommended", they mean "don't ever, ever do it". :) Really don't. Just don't.

Comment: I do not understand; :( When thread "TEST" is sleeping at this moment  t.wait() is invoked and - it does not hung. I do not understand why. If thread is terminated or new it hungs.

Comment: If it's terminated or new (unstarted), it won't call `notifyAll`, so nothing will wake up the main thread from the first `t.wait()`.

Comment: now I understand.  but "As it terminates, it calls notifyAll". where is this code? when thread is terminated automatically is this done? Where is the code written?

Comment: Just to be sure t.wait() is not putting thread t to waiting. The main thread which invoked main method is waiting.

Comment: You can use any object as monitor and call monitor.wait() and the calling thread will wait until another thread will call on the same monitor instance notify or notifyAll. Then waiting threads will continue.

Comment: Because Thread class uses notifyAll for special use case you should not use it as a monitor object.